# Determining overfitting model by computing variance in prediction error

Tags: machine-learning, variance, overfitting, white-noise

I have a data set for regression, with a set of input features and 1 response variable. To confirm if a trained model has overfitted, we can see if the train error << test error at untrained sample points. However, I want to know if the following can also indicate an overfit model in case I have some idea of the extent of inherent noise in the response set. I simply compute the training errors (i.e. prediction error at each observation of my train set) and then observe the variance in the errors. If this variance is significantly less than the expected variance of the noise distribution (assuming noise to be white noise from a Gaussian distribution), then the model has overfit.

For example, I believe the hidden noise in my response data to be from the following distribution N(0,0.05). If the variance in my model prediction train errors is say 0.01, it clearly means that my model has learnt the noise in addition to the non-noisy signal.
Does this make sense!

Comment: This is a good informal criterion for knowing when to stop improving a model.  You don't want to squeeze the error down to levels that are lower than the inherent variability in the data.  I wouldn't use a significance test as described here, though, because it still encourages overfitting: you have flipped the null and alternate hypotheses.  When the training errors *are not significantly greater* than what you expect, it's usually time to stop.

Comment: Agree @whuber. If I understand correctly, the better way to stop further training a model should be when "training errors are not significantly greater than what you expect", rather than training errors being significantly lower than some threshold. However, from a purely validation point of view (whether a trained model has overfit or not), the latter approach could be more handy to identify a potential overfit I believe. Obviously, as Tussel answered, intuition / assessment of the inherent noise would be crucial for decision making.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does make sense to me, but makes your decision rest on the accuracy of your assessment of the noise.